# Multiple Handlers to the UI thread

Tags: android

I am creating a `Handler` object on the UI thread, and then using it to `postDelayed`. At some point I want to cancel the pending delayed tasks. If I call `handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)` will it remove only pending tasks set via this `Handler` instance, or will it cancel all tasks pending on the UI thread, even if set by other `Handler` instances or by the OS itself?

Comment: just the pending tasks handled by your Handler

Comment: Please post this as an actual answer :)

Comment: @blackbelt I'd be happy to accept your answer and give you the credit if you make that an actual answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in blackbelt's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24487005/multiple-handlers-to-the-ui-thread#comment37904257_24487005) on the question, only what was set via this `Handler` instance gets canceled.